# Getting rid of outer foreach loop using linq or lambda and ensuring no duplicates are added to list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got 2 parts to this question:

1. Is there way to get rid of the outer loop

   ```
   List<Document> newDocuments = new List<Document>();
   foreach (DocumentDetail documentDetail in documentDetails)
   {
       newDocuments.AddRange(documents.FindAll(d => d.Extension.ToUpperInvariant() == documentDetail.Extension.ToUpperInvariant()));
   }
   ```
2. As you can see from the above, I'm just dealing with the "Extension" and even if I ended up keeping my outer foreach loop, I still want to check every other properties (i.e. description, etc...) so I may end up with multiple calls to the inner part and it will ended up looking like this, assuming I'm now checking Description

   ```
   newDocuments.AddRange(documents.FindAll(d => d.Description.ToUpperInvariant() == documentDetail.Description.ToUpperInvariant()));
   ```

The problem with the above is that I could end up with duplicate documents if a document happens to have a .pdf extension and then matches the description.

How can I ensure that no duplicates documents are added. Can I add something to my linq query (or to lambda?). In terms of uniqueness, while not definite, for now I have access to a "documentno" which is unique for all the documents held in the "documents" lists.

If you know the answer to one part or the other, please let me know.

Appreciated!

## Edited

What about this? It definitely works, but I'm not sure this is the right way to write this?

```
List<Document> newDocs = (from documentDetail in documentDetails
                          from document in documents
                          where document.Extension.ToUpperInvariant() == documentDetail.Extension.ToUpperInvariant()
                           select document).Distinct().ToList();
```

Am I better off just sticking to foreach loop?

Using the above, I would end up with something like this if I wanted to check multiple properties from the DocumentDetails list against my Document List:

```
        List<Document> newDocuments = null;

        if (documentDetails.FindAll(dd => (dd.Extension != null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dd.Extension))).Count > 0)
        {
            newDocuments = (from documentDetail in documentDetails
                            from document in documents
                            where document.Extension.ToUpperInvariant() == documentDetail.Extension.ToUpperInvariant()
                            select document).Distinct().ToList();
        }

        if (documentDetails.FindAll(dd => (dd.Description != null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dd.Description))).Count > 0)
        {
            newDocuments = (from documentDetail in documentDetails
                            from document in documents
                            where document.Description.ToUpperInvariant() == documentDetail.Description.ToUpperInvariant()
                            select document).Distinct().ToList();
        }
```

While I'd still like someone to confirm that the way I wrote this is correct, I'm still left with how to append the results and then remove all duplicates. I guess when all is done, I could apply the Distinct, but I'm still left with "appending" issue. How do I do this then?

Thanks.

Comment: `String.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of any duplicates before processing the list:

```
List<Document> newDocuments = new List<Document>();
List<Document> distinctItems = newDocuments .Distinct();
foreach (DocumentDetail documentDetail in documentDetails)
{
    newDocuments.AddRange(documents.FindAll(d => d.Extension.ToUpperInvariant() == documentDetail.Extension.ToUpperInvariant()));
}
```

Comment: The Distinct definitely will do the trick for one part, but I've edited my question, so hopefully it will be clearer what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at something like this: Not tested yet - class definitions would help!

```
var extensions = documentDetail.Select(d => d.Extension.ToUpperInvariant()).ToList();
var newDocuments = documents.Where(d => extensions.Contains(d.Extension.ToUpperInvariant())).ToList();
```

Comment: When following this model (Where -> Contains) you should have `extensions` be a `HashSet` rather than a `List` as it can be much more efficiently searched.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I didn't know that as I mostly do Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 0):

What you're logically doing here is a `Join`:

```
var newDocuments = documentDetails.Join(documents,
        documentDetail => documentDetail.Extension,
        document => document.Extension,
        (documentDetail, document) => document,
        StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Distinct();
```

(This could be done in query syntax, rather than method syntax, but then you couldn't supply the string comparer which allows you to compare the strings without needing to convert their case.  That's the appropriate way of performing a case insensitive comparison.)

This code is, from a functional standpoint, the exact same as your first edited version, except that it's *much* more efficient.  What you're doing is pairing up every single document with every single detail record and then filtering out just those that you need under the assumption that the item from each list has a "key" and you want the items where those keys match.  This is such a common operation that it has it's own special operator (Join).  It's also possible to optimize this specific case much more heavily than in your code.  The Join operator is capable of only creating those pairs that it needs; it doesn't need to match up a *lot* of items that don't belong together only to throw them out later.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tried it and it works fine, but it's a bit more complicated to understand. Can you show me how would I add an additional condition to this i.e. Compare Extension and Description for example? Thanks